# How do you seed non scoped named bindings using Guice ?

Tags: java, guice

Building a web based application using Guice and have this peculiar situation -

I am using a lot of method interceptors that are lightweight.

My question is - I have a named binding say "Operation.Current" the value of which needs to be changed when one of these interceptors executes within a  single request thread. So the bound value changes multiple times within a single request thread. I need this value to be injected as I need.

Currently I am using

`request.setAttribute(Key.get(Operation.class, Names.named("Operation.Current")).toString(), op);`

in my GuiceFilter to initialize the value. And I want to replace this value when the interceptors execute.

So I need to re seed my value present in the request as an attribute multiple times through the request.

What is a better way to solve this issue ? Since I see that the value is not in a real sense RequestScoped. So ideally this value should be non scoped and bound the name.

But how do I change the value as I need outside a Guice Module ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the module binding once you created the injector. If you know all instances in advance, try the [MapBinder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html), otherwise consider using a [provider-binding](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings), then you can evaluate the required instance dynamically for each call.

Comment: I am referring to named bindings whose values can be seeded. e.g. For request scoped named bindings I can seed a value at the beginning of a request. Since the binding is request scoped I should not be able to modify. However for a non scoped named binding I should be able to modify the value. Is my understanding correct ?